# AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'object' when importing tensorflow in my anaconda env

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, incompatibility

#### This was the error raised

`np.object` was a deprecated alias for the builtin `object`. To avoid this error in existing code, use `object` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe.
The aliases was originally deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance see the original release note at:
https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations

**My tensorflow is version 2.6.0 and Numpy version 1.25.0**

Nothing has worked so far, it seems like I was just juggling between pip install of different versions and it seems to open a can of worms and asking me to change different versions of packages I have.

### What I have done

1. I have tried `!pip install` to upgrade downgrade to solve compatibility issue but no dice
2. I have tried upgrading the tensorflow packages through Anaconda Navigator but it seems to
   have bug and just stuck at version 2.6.0

Answer (score 1):

I'm also using Tensorflow 2.6.0 and numpy 1.25.0 and ran into the same problem.  Since I already fixed it, I can't get screenshots of the errors anymore.  I also referred to that linked documentation, so we're on exactly the same page.  I'm confident this will help you.

Note: my Anaconda environment is named "tf_gpu"

The first error that `np.int` was deprecated appeared in

> anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py

Using the release notes, I went into that file and replaced all instances with `np.int_`.  I don't understand the difference nor why tensorflow hasn't incorporated that yet.

The second error that `np.bool` was deprecated appeared in the same file.  I once again replaced all `np.bool` with `np.bool_` per the numpy 1.25.0 release notes.

The third error popped up in the following folder:

> anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops

Since I already fixed it, I don't remember which file within this folder the error happened, but the solution was the same as before: replace `np.bool` with `np.bool_`.

After those changes, I didn't have any other issues.